# Infragistics Ultragrid - slow performance with PerformAutoResize

Tags: c#, ultrawingrid

I have badly performing code that uses Ultragrid, but running a visualisation analysis using D3.js on the trace output I discovered that grid__InitializeRow was calling itself multiple times.

Trigger created by: `this.grid.InitializeRow += new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeRowEventHandler(this.grid_InitializeRow);`

Problem starts with this code:

```
column.PerformAutoResize(PerformAutoSizeType.AllRowsInBand, true)
```

Searching the web I could not find information on this, but have found some possible contenders - calling any of these appears to call initialise row:

- grid.DataSource
- grid.Rows.Band.Layout.Bands
- column.performAutoResize

Questions

1. Is there documentation on this anywhere
2. Can I disable the trigger somehow temporarily

Thanks in advance

Comment: looking at http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.Aspx?ArticleID=3434 and http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.Aspx?ArticleID=2882 keep you posted

Comment: InitializeRow get's called each time the grid is redrawn. This happens when you refresh the grid, add a new datasource, sorting, etc. You can add/remove extra functionality using `public void grid_InitializeRow(Object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeRowEventArgs e)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't make "PerformAutoResize" perform adequately. It would take 10s of seconds. So in the end I decided to roll my own, which is limited to our particular use of the grid config which only displays text in cells (as opposed to sub-controls), using the Graphics.MeasureString function for each grid cell.

About 40 lines of code and reduced time taken to 0.4 secs for a 600 x 20 grid.

Comment: I found that it triggered a cascade of updates - think you did the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer via [Infragistics forums](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/17666.aspx):

Calling `column.PerformAutoResize(PerformAutoSizeType.AllRowsInBand, true)` triggers a rebind from the datasource, which in turn triggers `initialise_row`.

As the resize was called multiple times (once per column per band) the rebinds got out of hand.

For information we also had the following problems. With a year's data it was taking 2 minutes to render:

- It was a huge grid and the cells were being styled individually. Changing to using an Appearance library / factory shaved 40s off the load time
- Database tuning shaved another 40s off
- Changing the way custom totals rows were calculated shaved 15s off (by using total var instead of updating cell)
- AutoResize was a force multiplier - made all the other issues worse. Fixing that shaved more time off.

Hope this helps others with simiar problems